# Is there any command line docx to image converter available?

Tags: linux, windows, file-conversion, image-conversion

Is there any docx to image (jpg, png, bmp, ...) available with **`command line`** support? It's better to have one in windows, but if there is any in linux, that's great too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[VeryDOC's DOC to Any Converter](http://www.verydoc.com/doc-to-any.html) claims to be able to do what you want. However it's not free - 79$ per End User License of the CLI version.

It's as easy as:

`c:\doc2any_cmd>doc2any.exe mydocument.docx image_of_mydocument.bmp`

You can [download a trial version](http://www.verydoc.com/doc2any_cmd.zip) to see if it's upto your expectations. But it will riddle the output files with fugly watermarks.

Comment: I'll check it!!

Answer (score 3):

I realise this is a very old question, but it comes up high on search results so warranted a response. As another option that is not a paid product, take a look at libreoffice.

You can use their command line interface to convert documents that it can open to pdf. From there, you can use imagemagick to convert pdf to image.

A very basic example of how you can use libreoffice can be found in this discussion on askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/396825/convert-docx-to-pdf

Converting then from pdf to image would be something along these lines: